# OCTAVE data import from PCE-VDL data logger device and conversion of decimal coma to decimal point

Tags: import, type-conversion, decimal, octave, point

I have a measurement device PCE-VDL, which gives me measurements in following CSV format below, which I need to import to OCTAVE for further investigation.

Especially I need to import last 3 columns with xyz acceleration data.
The file is in CSV format with delimiter of semicolon ";".

I have tried:

```
A_1 = importdata ("file.csv", ";", 3);
```

but have recieved

```
error: missing_idx(10): out of bound 9
```

The CSV file looks like this:

```
@PCE-VDL X - TableView series
@2020.16.11
@Date;Time;Duration [s];t [°C];RH [%];p [mbar];aX [g];aY [g];aZ [g];
2020.28.10;16:16:32:0000;00:000;;;;0,0195;-0,0547;1,0039;
2020.28.10;16:16:32:0052;00:005;;;;0,0898;-0,0273;0,8789;
2020.28.10;16:16:32:0104;00:010;;;;0,0977;-0,0313;0,9336;
2020.28.10;16:16:32:0157;00:015;;;;0,1016;-0,0273;0,9297;
```

The numbers in last 3 columns have also decimal coma and not decimal point. So there probably should be done also some conversion.

Thank you very much for any help.
Regards

**EDIT: 18.11.2020**
Thanks for help. I have tried now following:

```
A_1_str = fileread ("file.csv"); 
A_1_str_m = strrep (A_1_str, ".", "-");
A_1_str_m = strrep (A_1_str_m, ",", ".");
save "A_1_str_m.csv" A_1_str_m;

A_1 = importdata ("A_1_str_m.csv", ";", 8);
```

and still receive error: file_content(140): out of bound 139

There is probably some problem with time format in first columns, which I do not want to read. I just need last three columns.
After my conversion, the file looks like this:

```
# Created by Octave 5.1.0, Wed Nov 18 21:40:52 2020 CET <zdenek@ASUS-F5V>
# name: A_1_str_m
# type: sq_string
# elements: 1
# length: 7849
@PCE-VDL X - TableView series
@2020-16-11
@Date;Time;Duration [s];t [°C];RH [%];p [mbar];aX [g];aY [g];aZ [g];
2020-28-10;16:16:32:0000;00:000;;;;0.0195;-0.0547;1.0039;
2020-28-10;16:16:32:0052;00:005;;;;0.0898;-0.0273;0.8789;
2020-28-10;16:16:32:0104;00:010;;;;0.0977;-0.0313;0.9336;
```

Thanks for support!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can first read the data with `fileread`, which stores the data as a string. Then you can manipulate the string like this:

```
new_string = strrep(string, ",", ".");
```

`strrep` replaces all occurrences of a pattern within a string. Afterwards you save this data as a separate file or you overwrite the existing file with the manipulated data. When this is done you proceed as you have tried before.

**EDIT: 19.11.2020**

To avoid the additional heading lines in the new file, you can save it like this:

```
fid = fopen("A_1_str_m.csv", "w");
fputs(fid, A_1_str_m);
fclose(fid);
```

`fputs` will just write the string to the file.

The you can read the new file with `dlmread`.

```
A1_buf = dlmread("A_1_str_m.csv", ";");
A1_buf = real(A1);           # get the real value of the complex number
A1_buf(1:3, :) = [];         # remove the headlines
A1 = A1_buf(:, end-3:end-1); # get only the the 3 columns you're looking for
```

This will give you the three columns your looking for. But the date and time data will be ignored.

**EDIT 20.11.2020**

Replaced `abs` with `real`, so the sign of the value will be kept.

Comment: Thank you very much! It worked and I have sucessfully loaded the data. I have just removed your line "A1_buf = abs(A1);" because this made absolute values of the acceleration data, which is not needed. I will publish as an answer to this question my complete code. I very appreciate your help! Kind Regards

Comment: You're welcome. I overlooked that that absolute value would affect the result. But you can replace `abs()` with `real()`, so that you keep the sign of the value and the matrix will also not have the complex attribute. L'll edit this in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use `csv2cell` from the `io` package.